Using VS Find & Replace Regex across lines
I have multiple instances of code that looks like...
if (condition) {
    statements
}
else if (different condition) {
    statements
}

ad nauseum (probably, honestly about 100+ different times, and in different files).
I've been slowly working on fixing them so that they instead do:
if (condition) {
    statements
} else if (different condition) {
    statements
} else if (different condition) {

My question is there should be some regex that allows me to grab the line with just the closing brace, and the line that starts else if and merge them together to be } else if with a replace (which should bring the rest of the else if condition in line with it...)
But I'm stumped as to finding what combination actually does this!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Try wildcard search for : }\nelse if replace by } else if.

So, after playing some more, I found that if I did \t}(\r\n)(\t)else if would then find the instances of
}
else if (condition) {
... and so on...

and then use \t} else if in the replacement field made the changes I wanted made.

The regex substitution is simple enough, with Perl or Extended regex it would look like this (taking height for extra white spaces):
s/\}\s*\r?\n\s*else\s+if\s*/} else if /

The tricky part might be to feed the substituion the multiple lines as one string instead of line by line. With perl you can do that using -00 (telling perl to use the null byte as input record separator), so this:
  perl -00 -pe 's/\}\s*\n\r?\s*else\s+if\s*/} else if /g' -i /tmp/file.code

would replace all
  }
  else if

occurences in your file.code with
  } else if

OBSERVE the /g option in the substitution to replace all occurrences. Without it only the first occurrence will be replaced.
